# After fixing issue in computer and pushing code to server, error still shows in server

Tags: .net, web-services, c#-4.0

Here's the background info:

I'm working on a .net 4.0 web service that's already been deployed into our dev and our test environments. Our dev server is pretty useless because the data is so jacked up from development that we do our testing in test for the most part.

Well, there are errors showing up in our test environment that I KNOW should no longer be an issue because I fixed the code for the web service. However, after I publish into my pc, copy the dll's to dev and test and run the system that calls this web service in test, the same issue comes up.

I have checked the timestamps on my pc and our test environment and they're the same. I'm a relatively new developer so I'm still learning so I'm wondering if maybe the code is cached somewhere that needs to be cleared, because I can't come up with any other solutions.

One last thing, the web config in my PC is setup so that I test our TEST accounts. So yes, **I am** working with the same data that the test web service is, and when I debug an account in my pc it works fine, but when I run the same process from the system that calls my web service the same old issue comes up.

**Update:** The test server has been restarted and everything, the issue is still there even though, again, all the dll's have the most recent time stamp.

Comment: Are you using dynamic compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing an IIS reset?

Comment: Yep, did IIS reset, restarted server, the whole nine yards.